# Batch test if python.exe is running specific file

Tags: windows, cmd

I am making a web controller for a python service, so that a user can start and stop the service. I need to be able to know whether the service is running.

I want to check whether python is running my script from `cmd`. `echo 1` if it is running my script otherwise `echo 0`

such as:

```
if (python is running bot.py) (
    echo 1
)
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, please edit and add more details

Comment: added sort of an example

Comment: You can create an actual Windows service using PyWin32. A service can be started, stopped, and queried using the service API or from the command line via sc.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky in plain cmd, but this seems to work:

```
@echo off
tasklist.exe /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FO LIST | find "bot.py" >nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   echo 0
) else (
    echo 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best off having a file that is created by the running bots, which contains their PID, and then checking for the presence of this file. It would allow you to get the PID, but it does rely on the processes being terminated cleanly.

This works similarly to lock files, which can be used to stop 2 instances of a program running on the same data at the same time.